# Displaying First Collection That Was Assigned to Product

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to change my product breadcrumb to display the first collection of a product (rather than showing the path the user took to reach the product).

I'm using the code `product.collections[0]` to show the first collection... but this displays the collections in A-Z order rather than the first collection that was added to the product.

Is there a way to call the first collection that was added to the product rather than ordering it A-Z?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually there is nothing in Shopify to support your cause. If you have a product you can get the list of collections it belongs to, but there is no support for a hierarchy or temporal access time. If you need to keep track of which collections a customer hits per product, you will need to do that yourself, manually, with JS.

Ever since day 0 of Shopify, I am sure there has been a wish for Shopify to somehow keep track of the collection that was selected when a customer selected a product, but to date, even that is not supported at all.